# Meaning of “source published articles”

Tags: meaning

I'm applying for a new writers job and before the interview I received an email asking me to source published articles!
I'm not sure what she meant by that.  Does she want me to show her some of my articles or write new ones?

This is her email:

> Can you please source 10 published articles for us to review internally?

Comment: She wants you to give her the links to ten of your published articles, or to send them to her.  (As an aside, proofread them for typos.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because explaining the meaning of correspondence is off topic.

Comment: @Sara - I'm afraid this question isn't really a good fit for this site. You have two options to answer this question: 1. Use a dictionary to look up what "source" means; 2. Ask whoever wrote the email. I'm afraid this site isn't a dictionary service: we won't do option no1 for you. If you've already looked in a dictionary, and can't interpret what she means, then you'll have to ask her what she meant because we don't know what someone else is thinking!

Answer (score 1):

I take it as asking you to provide the souce (a web link, journal citation etc) to 10 articles you have authored and had published. And 'published' would imply in some reasonably notable type of orginization such as a media outlet or learned society. Something more than say a blog.